# SSRS Lookup Based on Multiple Conditions

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a dataset (Volume) looks like this:

[image]

In my report, what I want to get is this:

[image]

The Lookup expression: =Lookup (Fields!Id.Value, Fields!Id.Value,      Fields!Volume.Value,"Volume") can only lookup on ID. Is there any way I can do lookup on ID first, and then lookup on Sub_Group to get the correct Volume? Thank you.

Comment: Is Volume your only dataset, or are you using Lookup to match it to another dataset?

Comment: Volume is not the only dataset. I am using it to get Volume in the report. The report is based on a different dataset :)

Comment: You have to post both datasets to determine how the lookup expression should be. Do you want to join both datasets in a matrix?

Comment: thanks:)The main dataset has ID, that's the only key can link to Volume DS. I tried to avoid join the two datasets, but I think the best way is using LookUp...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can `Lookup` using multiple fields if you concatenate all the necessary fields in the first and second `Lookup` parameter.

```
=Lookup(Fields!ID.Value & Fields!SUB_GROUP.Value, Fields!ID.Value & Fields!SUB_GROUP.Value, Fields!VOLUME.Value, "Volume")
```

Alternatively, you can concatenate all the necessary fields in your dataset and use that for your `Lookup`.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the logic. But the Fields!SUB_GROUP.Value is not in the main dataset, which I am using for the report. Any other way around?

Comment: So I take it columns A, B and C are static columns in a tablix, rather than a matrix column group? If so, you could hard-code the subgroup into the expression in each column. `=Lookup(Fields!ID.Value & "A", Fields!ID.Value & Fields!SUB_GROUP.Value, Fields!VOLUME.Value, "Volume")`

Comment: Yup, this is what I need. A, B and C are not static columns, but I can figure out a way by following the logic you suggested. Thank you very much.